# not understanding AWS Amplify authentication flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am trying to create a custom AWS Amplify authentication flow with code similar to the following taken from amazon's website:

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

async function signUp() {
    try {
        const user = await Auth.signUp({
            username,
            password,
            attributes: {
                email,          // optional
                phone_number,   // optional - E.164 number convention
                // other custom attributes 
            }
        });
        console.log({ user });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error signing up:', error);
    }
}
```

I have a few questions about this.

1. How are the tokens refreshed?  If I am saving the credentials in the user variable, is this automatically refreshed somehow behind the scenes?
2. How do I make authenticated graphql requests after I add a graphql api?  With the pre-baked authentication flow it keeps track of who you are automatically.  How do I do this when I log in this way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, they are refreshed when necessary, except if you are using a different social provider. You can find more information on their documentation [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/working-with-api/q/platform/ios#managing-security-tokens), [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/advanced/q/platform/js#token-refresh) and [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/overview/q/platform/js#authentication-with-aws)

> By default, Amplify will automatically refresh the tokens for Google
>   and Facebook, so that your AWS credentials will be valid at all times.
>
> ...
>
> you do not need to refresh Amazon Cognito tokens manually. The tokens
>   are automatically refreshed by the SDK when necessary.
>
> ...
>
> use Auth.signUp and Auth.signIn (or an Amplify UI component) to
>   complete this process and retrieve tokens. The Amplify client will
>   refresh the tokens calling Auth.currentSession if they are no longer
>   valid.

2. When you instantiate your AppSync client you define how it is going to retrieve the token
   i.e:

```js
    const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
        url: config.aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint,
        region: config.aws_appsync_region,
        auth: {
          type: config.aws_appsync_authenticationType,
          apiKey: config.aws_appsync_apiKey,
          jwtToken: async () => (await Auth.currentSession()).getIdToken().getJwtToken(),
        },
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @danielfranca!

Comment: Hi @danielfranca.  One more question.  So for the signup code above I can just store the user in a state and authenticate that way with my api calls?

Comment: if when you say state you mean the config object, yes